# how to make implicit grid item take up full parent width?

Tags: css, grid

I have a codepen here : [IMPLICIT GRID ITEM](https://codepen.io/laiqa-mohid/pen/gOdZoNW)

Firstly - I have a list of grid containers with atleast 3 items in each.
Secondly - these rows have a system where for every **even** container, the grid defined has 3 columns while for every **odd** container the grid defined has 2 columns.

In the **odd** parent, there is an implicit 3rd item that gets pushed into a new row.
I need to know if there is a way to make this implicit item take up full width of it's parent. I need a way to do this by without having to target individual items.

didn't want to use span on individual elements grid-column is not animatable with CSS. is there a way to do this with just grid-template-rows or column or implicit auto stuff?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="item">1</span>
 <span class="item">2</span>
<!--   implicit item  -->
   <span class="item">3</span> 
  <!--   implicit item  -->
</div>
<div class="row">
  <span class="item">1</span>
 <span class="item">2</span>
   <span class="item">3</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  
<!--   <span class="item">1</span> -->
 <span class="item">2</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aqua;
   grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're setting the odd grid parents to a 2 column layout you could set every 3rd element to span the full width by using [grid-column](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-row-column/) as per the code below

Is that what you're looking for?

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

/* added this - make every 3rd element in your odd rows span the full column. */
.row:nth-child(odd) .item:nth-child(3n) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <span class="item">1</span>
  <span class="item">2</span>
  <span class="item">3</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <span class="item">1</span>
 <span class="item">2</span>
 <span class="item">3</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <span class="item">1</span>
 <span class="item">2</span>
 <span class="item">3</span>
</div>
```

**Edited to add** the elements inside your grid cells don't have to be the full size of the cell. See code below. As stated in the comment, you can just use divs and animate them

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}

.row:nth-child(odd) .item:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 2;
  width: 50%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  animation: widen 2s infinite;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}

@keyframes widen {
  0%,
  100% {
    width: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi there, I didn't want to use span on individual elements as they are not animatable with CSS. is there a way to do this with just grid-template-rows or column or implicit auto stuff?

Comment: I am willing to change the structure of the code to achieve this layout effect if it means using just grid template rows/columns.

Comment: You don' t need to use spans in your grid parent. divs are fine (and more common tbh). The child element inside the grid cell does also not have to be the same size as the grid cell. You can make it smaller and then animate it. I'll pop up an edit to my answer to show you how.